# What's the best way to deal with ASP.NET's ClientID

Tags: jquery, asp.net, clientid

I'm trying to find the best way to deal with the way that ASP.NET prepends a value to any element that is created with `runat="server"`, without having to resort to using `<%= id.ClientID %>`. I came up with the following solution earlier today, but I'm sure that there are more elegant solutions:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dotNetPrefix = $("[id$='prepended_ID_value']").attr('id');
        if (dotNetPrefix !== undefined) {
            dotNetPrefix = dotNetPrefix.replace('prepended_ID_value', '');
            dotNetPrefixID = '#' + dotNetPrefix;
            console.log('dotNetPrefix = ' + dotNetPrefix);
            testDotNet('prepended_ID_value');
        } else {
            console.log('Hidden Field is Missing! => <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="prepended_ID_value" Value="dotNet_ID_Prefix" />');
        }

    });

    function testDotNet(getID) {
        var test_dotNetPrefixID = $(dotNetPrefixID + getID).val();
        console.log('$(\'' + dotNetPrefixID + getID + '\').val() = ' + test_dotNetPrefixID);
    }
```

One problem with this method is that it requires that I place the following hidden field in every page: 
`<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="prepended_ID_value" Value="dotNet_ID_Prefix" />`
...and that makes it kinda klunky (or adds to the existing klunkiness factor).

My ultimate goal is to make it so that I no longer have to use `<%= id.ClientID %>` (or anything that requires server side code) so that all of my JS can be called as an include instead of having to embed it in my ASPX pages. Oh, my second ultimate goal is that it's as simple as possible and doesn't require a lot of setup time from project to project.

I created a JSFiddle with an example http://jsfiddle.net/Realto619/8ZZYt/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [ClientIDMode=Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx)?  Set it in the Web.config so that your client IDs will be as-written throughout the site.

Comment: Because I was not aware that was an option. That sounds like it meets my criteria spot on. I'll give that a shot and see how it works out. Thanks!

Comment: This is "bad practice", and i will give one example to why is bad, suppose that you have 3 controllers with div elment with the id `supposeToBeUniqe`
, now you load all those 3 controllers in an aspx page > there are 3 id's on the page with the same name!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **.Net framework 4.0 or higher** ,Use the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property of the Control

You may use Static as the [ClientIDModeEnumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx)

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the
>   control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the
>   hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

Comment: I've used `ClientIDMode=Predictable` before, but that still required more of my attention than I wanted. I obviously missed the `ClientIDMode=Static` option and it seems ideally suited for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery ends with selector:

`$('input[id$="myServerId"]')`

But remember, that kind of selector is a lot slower than selecting directly with the id with `<%= id.ClientID %>`.

http://jsperf.com/id-vs-ends-with

Comment: I actually used that in my "klunky" solution, but I figured that it would add too much overhead and slow things down beyond an acceptable amount.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is as follow

```
var txt1 = $('#<%= txt1.ClientID %>');
$(txt1).click(function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

her I create a new variable on the javascript which is reference to the control based on its rendered client ID