# Cannot access textbox from jQuery using ClientID

Tags: jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to deal with ASP.NET’s ClientID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614042/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-asp-nets-clientid)

I have the forllowing jQuery statement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready($('#<%=email.ClientID%>').keydown(function ()
    {
    alert("dsadsd");
    }
    )
        );
</script>
```

the textbox is-->

```
<asp:TextBox name="email" runat="server" ID="email" CausesValidation="True" 
                            ValidationGroup="email" ></asp:TextBox>
```

It does not execute when I type

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox name="email" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ID="email" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="email" ></asp:TextBox>

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#email').keydown(function(){
        alert("test");
      })    
   });
```