# Show hide td using javascript based on checkbox check and uncheck

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have to show hide td based on the checkbox checked and unchecked, if the checkbox is checked then it td should be visible else, it shouldn't be visible.

The code is showing no error but show and hide is not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("<%=chkrecurring.ClientID%>");
  tddays = $('#<%=tddays1.ClientID %>'); //document.getElementById("< %=tddays1.ClientID%>");
  alert(tddays);
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    //tddays.style.display = "block";
    tddays.show();
  } else {
    //tddays.style.display = "none";
    tddays.hide();
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="label-data">
                Recurring:
            </label>
      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkrecurring" onclick="javascript:myFunction();" />
    </td>
    <td id="tddays1" runat="server">
      <label class="label-data">
                No. of Days:<span class="red-txt">*</span>
            </label>
      <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtDays" MaxLength="4" CssClass="form-control">
        <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
      </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqdays" ControlToValidate="txtDays" ErrorMessage="Please enter number of days." ValidationGroup="valGrpAPat" Display="None">
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

My telerik html:-
[image]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please remove all server code and replace with relevant HTML

Comment: Also why have jQuery AND DOM access?

Comment: Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614042/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-asp-nets-clientid

Comment: @mplungjan yes, have jQuery access

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery consistently.
Assuming the issue is a clientID issue you can fix using [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614042/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-asp-nets-clientid), your code should be

```js
$('#chkrecurring').on('change', function() {
  $('#tddays1').toggle(this.checked)
})
```

```css
#tddays1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="label-data">Recurring:<input type="checkbox" id="chkrecurring" /></label>
    </td>
    <td id="tddays1">
      <label class="label-data">No. of Days:<span class="red-txt">*</span>
        <input type="number" id="txtDays" maxlength="4" class="form-control">
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am getting error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: As I said, you need to fix your IDs.

Comment: Fixed the Ids using ClientIDMode="Static" but still the same issue

Comment: Please post an example of the HTML generated by your telerik.

Comment: I have added image of telerik html in my main question

Comment: And does that translate to `$('#ct100_Content_txtDays')` in the code?

Comment: I mean in `view-source` !

Comment: Yes in view-source it is $('#ct100_Content_txtDays')

Comment: And jQuery is loaded?

Comment: Can you show the select and txtDays in rendered HTML?

Comment: I changed $('#<%=chkrecurring.ClientID%>').change(function() ,it is working. but $('#<%=tddays1.ClientID %>').toggle(this.checked) is not working

Comment: It should. I need to see the rendered HTML and rendered script, please

Comment: Just show the select and the txtDays fields - you can change content if it is personal

Comment: it is redering as same asp textbox in UI

Comment: See my example. You just need to make your ASP render similar using similar IDs. As you can see my code works

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your server codes and use the relevant HTML tags. This fixed the issue for me.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="label-data">
                Recurring:
            </label>
      <input type='checkbox' runat="server" ID="chkrecurring" onclick="javascript:myFunction();" checked/>
    </td>
    <td id="tddays1" runat="server">
      <label class="label-data">
                No. of Days:<span class="red-txt">*</span>
            </label>
      <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtDays" MaxLength="4" CssClass="form-control">
        <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
      </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqdays" ControlToValidate="txtDays" ErrorMessage="Please enter number of days." ValidationGroup="valGrpAPat" Display="None">
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("chkrecurring");
  tddays = document.getElementById("tddays1");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    tddays.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    tddays.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/karthikrab/76fuh8wt/